# Simulate pagebreake effect for uploaded HTML tables

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'v been seeking for the answer for to my problem for a long time, but still don't know how to handle it.

Here I have a page, and the size of "Page" is fixed. It's content is my uploaded HTML file which consist of multiple tables with multiple lines(I don't know how to implement uploading here in stackoverflow so i put them in the HTML directly).

Due to the size of paper is fixed, some part of my tables are being hidden. So what i need to do is to display them in multiple pages, which should be looks like the sketch below.

This is the sketch: >>>[click to see](http://imm.io/18CnE)<<<

And this is the sample in fiddle: >>>[FIDDLE SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/EVzKb/1/)<<<

Here are part of my codes in my project:

```
function xx (){

var fi = document.getElementById('fi').files[0];          

    reader.onload = function (e){            
        var reader = new FileReader();                     
        var inner ="";
        inner  += this.result;

        inn.innerHTML ="<center><div class='bg' id='0'><div id='testmain'>"+inner+"</div></div></center>";

    }

    reader.onerror = function (e){
        dd.innerHTML = "error<br>";
    }
    reader.readAsText(fi);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So the question is how to avoid one table showing on two pages?

Comment: Is the data being retrieved from a database via php? I know you didn't tag php but i'm just checking. If so i would do this with php and mySql.

Comment: to Shomz: no, just like in Microsoft Word, if we create multiple tables with large content, it should be shown in multiple A4-sized paper.

Comment: to Vector：just local .html files ^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS2 gives you [some control over page breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-break-props) when printing using things like `page-break-before: always;`, but it will only work in modern browsers.

Comment: yes, I can simply insert a div containing the page-break-before attribute and implement it in print. however, i should show the users how their reports looks like before printing.

Comment: @Darklizard Then you can use a `screen`-only CSS for styling up that `div` on screen, for example by adding a grey top border and top margin.